# Invoking Amazon Lex using audio recorded from capacitor-voice-recorder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, audio, amazon-lex, amazon-polly

**TLDR;** How to convert  `audio/webm;codecs=opus` to `audio/l16; rate=16000; channels=1` in python.

---

### The issue

I am using `capacitor-voice-recorder` to record audio in my Ionic application. In firefox its recording audio in `audio/webm;codecs=opus` format. It seems Amazon Lex requires PCM format:

- PCM format, audio data must be in little-endian byte order.

  - audio/l16; rate=16000; channels=1
  - audio/x-l16; sample-rate=16000; channel-count=1
  - audio/lpcm; sample-rate=8000; sample-size-bits=16; channel-count=1; is-big-endian=false

I know nothing about audio, so apologies in advance.

I send this audio as a base64 encoded string to a Lambda function which is written in python, and invokes Lex which looks like this:

```
def get_lex(recording):
    
    try:
        response = client.recognize_utterance(
                botId='',
                botAliasId='',
                localeId='en_US',
                sessionId=str(uuid.uuid4()),
                requestContentType='audio/l16; rate=16000; channels=1',
                responseContentType='text/plain; charset=utf-8',
                inputStream=recording
            )
            
        return decode(response['interpretations'])

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Decode Base64 string into bytes
    decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(event['body'])
        
    response = get_lex(decoded_bytes)
```

### The Question

My question is, how can I convert the audio which I have to a format which is acceptable by Amazon Lex. I can do it in either my application in Javascript, or in my Lambda function in Python.

Anything that I have searched points me to ffmpeg but I don't believe that's a valid option for me in Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing such an issue, here is the code that worked for me:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    input_audio_base64 = event['body']
    input_audio_bytes = base64.b64decode(input_audio_base64)
    
    ffmpeg_cmd = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i", "pipe:0",  # Use pipe input
        "-f", "wav",
        "-ar", "16000",
        "-ac", "1",
        "-acodec", "pcm_s16le",
        "pipe:1",  # Use pipe output
    ]
    
    process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate(input=input_audio_bytes)
    
    response = get_lex(output)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response), 
            'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
        }
    }
```